# Forbidden Error Invalid Csrf Token in Nodejs with F5 load balancer

Tags: java, node.js, csrf, f5

we hosting an application(nodejs(frontend)+ java(backend)) on azure kubernetes service with F5 load balancer in front. we have some API calls at node js layer. All the GET api calls succeded, but POST fails with invalid csrf token error which can i see on browser, in  nodejs side i can see that it doesnt make the POST call, it fails before making the call.

However without F5 loadbalancer this error never occurs.

I have validated _csrf and XSRF_TOKEN token on cookie, both GET and POST the request they seems to be same.